# Is it possible to develop function that returns the number (rank, position) of a particular permutation.

Tags: permutations

I'm working on a data warehousing project and need to assign a unique value to a permutation and store that value as dimension in the data warehouse.  Currently, I'm relying upon a rather large lookup table to determine the unique value and I'm curious if it would be possible to achieve the same result via a function or algorithm.

Here is a small scale example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Assume you have three values: 1, 2 and 3.  Assuming order does not matter there are $3 \times 3 \times 3$ possible permutation.  If you were develop a lookup table with all the possibilities it might look something like the following:

1. 111
2. 112
3. 113
4. ...
    ...
5. 333

Now if I code the sequences 112 and 333 I would assign the values of 2 and 27, respectively.   The look-up table approach works fine when you have three possible values in three possible position, but as the values and positions increase the look-up approach quickly loses its appeal.

My question is it possible to right a function (psuedo code or otherwise) that given a combination it yields the permutation's or unique value). Alternatively, is there a hash function that would have desirable properties.

Comment: use the factorial number system.

Comment: @abel thanks for the response. I just went to Wikipedia to read up on the factorial number system and I'm a little bit out of my depth.  Could I trouble you to perhaps demonstrate its application to my example.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just want to code in base three, that is associate to the triple $a_{1} a_{2} a_{3}$ the number
$$
1 + (a_{1} - 1) \cdot 9 + (a_{2} - 1) \cdot 3 + (a_{3} - 1).
$$

This becomes much cleaner if you use $0, 1, 2$, and start counting at $0$, then it's
$$
b_{2} b_{1} b_{0} \mapsto b_{2} \cdot 9 + b_{1} \cdot 3 + b_{0}
$$,
that is

- $000 \mapsto 0$
- $001 \mapsto 1$
- etc
- $222 \mapsto 26$

Conversely, given a number $c$ between $0$ and $26$, you reconstruct $b_{0}, b_{1}, b_{2}$ by first dividing $c$ by $3$ to get $b_{0}$:
$$
c = 3 c_{1} + b_{0}, 0 \le b_{0} < 3
$$
then dividing $c_{1}$ by $3$ to get $b_{1}, b_{2}$:
$$
c_{1} = 3 b_{2} + b_{1}, 0 \le b_{1} < 3.
$$

Comment: Andreas -Thanks! - this is exactly what I was looking for.  How would this equation change if I had 8 values instead of three (i.e. a1a2a3a4a5a6a7a8)

Comment: $b_{7} b_{6} \dots b_{1} b_{0} \mapsto b_{7} \cdot n^{7} + b_{6} \cdot n^{6} + \dots + b_{0}$ if each $b_{i}$ takes $n$ values